# como instalar uan version antigua de una libreria

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip

Estoy intentando crear la documentación de mi proyecto que usa una versión antigua de flask me gustaría poder poner el comando para instalar la versión de flask que estoy usando en el proyecto

Comment: `pip install flask=version.que.necesites`

Comment: Y por cierto, si haces `pip install freeze` te mostrará todos los paquetes que tienes instalados en ese momento, y la versión instalada de cada uno de ellos, por si ya no sabes qué versiones eran

Comment: Yo opinaría que otra forma seria buscar en la página oficial de la librería, ellos deben tener un historial de versiones y lo deberías descargar e instalar en tu proyecto la que tu necesites